# PHP - Force eval() to run in global scope

Tags: php, function, scope, eval

*[This is not a duplicate, as my requirements are that the eval() statement MUST be in the function. Also, I do not require that the function “set_myvar” return anything at all. How do I mark this as NOT a duplicate?]*

Say I have this code (ignore how silly it is; it's just hypothetical):

```
$myvar = null;
function set_myvar(){
eval("$myvar = 'Hello world';");
}
set_myvar();
echo $myvar;
```

Can I force eval() to be called in the global scope, so that the program echoes "Hello world"?

Comment: Just have your `eval` return a value and set it that way [Example](https://3v4l.org/pJigY)

Comment: @Machavity I cannot have the eval() return a value, according to how I will be using it. In my special case it must execute in the global scope. Can you please un-mark this as duplicate?

Comment: Ask a new question, indicating the research you did, and why that question is not a duplicate of yours. I think I may have a solution but it's hacky, and almost certainly won't fit in a comment anyway...

Comment: Post a more complete example then. I'm happy to reopen but, given your limited code, that's how to fix it.

Comment: @Machavity I re-submitted the same question and got an answer.

Comment: @user3163495 I will recommend that, in the future, you not post a duplicate question to circumvent a closure.  You might like to delete this question now.